# What are exact specification for a type to be a (1) sequence (2) iterable type in Python?

Tags: python, collections

What methods must be implemented in a class definition so that it can be considered as a sequence type and an iterable type? And if there's a formal definition for them can you also provide a reference to PEP or another document where it is defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html):

An iterable is:

> A object with an `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()` method.  Examples of
>   iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple)
>   and some non-sequence types like dict and file. When an iterable
>   object is passed as an argument to the builtin function iter(), it
>   returns an iterator for the object. This iterator is good for one pass
>   over the set of values.

An iterator is:

> An iterable which has a next() method.  Iterators are required to have
>   an `__iter__()` method that returns the iterator object itself. An
>   iterator is good for one pass over the set of values.

A sequence is:

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer
>   indices via the `__getitem__()` special method and defines a len()
>   method that returns the length of the sequence. Some built-in sequence
>   types are list, str, tuple, and unicode. Note that dict also supports
>   `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`, but is considered a mapping rather
>   than a sequence because the lookups use arbitrary immutable keys
>   rather than integers.

Answer (score 2):

The collections module defines abstract base classes for defining sequences and iterables.  For iterable you must define `__iter__`, for sequence you must define `__getitem__`.  See http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes .