# Generate all possible sublists of a list by keys

Tags: python

I have data like

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 13, 113]
```

which I then want to sort into separate lists by keys generated by myself. In fact I want to generate *all* possible lists.

Some examples:

```
values: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 13, 113]
keys:   [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3,  3,   1]
sublists: [2, 2], [2, 2, 113], [2], [3, 13]

values: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 13, 113]
keys:   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,  1,   0]
sublists: [2, 2, 2, 2, 113], [2, 3, 13]

values: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 13, 113]
keys:   [2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4,  1,   3]
sublists: [2, 2], [13], [2], [2, 113], [2, 3]
```

All possible keys are generated by

```
def generate_keys(prime_factors):
    key_size = len(prime_factors) - 1
    key_values = [str(i) for i in range(key_size)]

    return list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(key_values, \
        len(prime_factors)))
```

Then I thought I could use the keys to shift the values into the sublists. That's the part I'm stuck on. I thought itertools.groupby would be my solution but upon further investigation I see no way to use my custom lists as keys for groupby.

How do I split my big list into smaller sublists using these keys? There may even be a way to do this without using keys. Either way, I don't know how to do it and looking at other Stack Overflow questions has eben in the ballpark but not exactly this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
def sift(keys, values):
    answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
    kvs = zip(keys, values)
    for k,v in kvs:
        answer[k].append(v)
    return [answer[k] for k in sorted(answer)]

In [205]: keys = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3,  3,   1]

In [206]: values = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 13, 113]

In [207]: sift(keys,values)
Out[207]: [[2, 2], [2, 2, 113], [2], [3, 13]]
```

**Explanation**:

[collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a handy `dict`-like class that lets you define what should happen in the event that a key doesn't exist in the dictionary that you're trying to manipulate. For example, in my code, I have `answer[k].append(v)`. We know that `append` is a `list` function, so we know that `answer[k]` should be a list. However, if I was using a conventional `dict` and I tried to `append` to the value of a non-existent key, I would have gotten a `KeyError` as follows:

```
In [212]: d = {}

In [213]: d[1] = []

In [214]: d
Out[214]: {1: []}

In [215]: d[1].append('one')

In [216]: d[1]
Out[216]: ['one']

In [217]: d
Out[217]: {1: ['one']}

In [218]: d[2].append('two')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/USER/<ipython-input-218-cc58f739eefa> in <module>()
----> 1 d[2].append('two')

KeyError: 2
```

This was only made possible because I defined `answer = collections.defaultdict(list)`. If I had defined `answer = collections.defaultdict(int)`, I would gotten a different error - one that would tell me that `int` objects don't have an `append` method.

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) on the other hand takes two `list`s (well actually, it takes at least two [`iterable`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765451/what-are-exact-specification-for-a-type-to-be-a-1-sequence-2-iterable-type-i)), lets call them `list1` and `list2` and returns a list of tuples in which the `i`th tuple contains two objects. The first is `list1[i]` and the second is `list2[i]`. If `list1` and `list2` are of unequal length, `len(zip(list1, list2))` would be the smaller value among `len(list1)` and `len(list2)` (i.e. `min(len(list1), len(list2))`.

Once I've zipped `keys` and `values`, I want to create a dict such that maps a value from `keys` to a list of values from `values`. This is why I used a `defaultdict`, so that I wouldn't have to check for the existence of a key in it before I appended to its value. If I had used a conventional dict, I would have had to do this:

```
answer = {}
kvs = zip(keys, values)
for k,v, in kvs:
    if k in answer:
        answer[k].append(v)
    else:
        answer[k] = [v]
```

Now that you have a `dict` (or a `dict`-like object) that maps values from `keys` to lists of `int`s that share the same key, all you need to do is get the lists which are the values of `answer` in sorted order, sorted by the keys of `answer`. `sorted(answer)` gives me a list of all of `answer`s keys in sorted order.

Once I have this list of sorted keys, all I have to do is get their values, which are lists of ints, and put all those lists into one big list and return that big list.

… annnnnd Done! Hope that helps

Comment: did you know you are a TOTAL BOSS!?!?!? Cause you are.

Comment: ps. if you are happy to provide a slight bit of explanation to what some things like zip, defaultdict do that would be awesome - sometimes the docs are a little complicated and examples like this make it simpler. That is a bonus though

Comment: @nebffa defaultdict is an extension of dictionary that allows a dictionary to have a default value.  The reason we need one of these is because of the `append` function; we're adding values to a list.  The problem is, if this list doesn't exist at the time of the `append`, we get an error. Defaultdict prevents that.

zip is function that takes the first object from one list, and the second object from one list, puts them into a tuple, and then outputs that to a list.  and repeats that, for the duration of the list.  We're using it here to assign your key to your value, to prep the dictionary.

Comment: @kreativitea thanks for your help. I could work out the zip but wasn't sure on the defaultdict

Comment: @nebffa: added the explanation that you asked for :)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thanks so much for going to the extra effort! I have already used defaultdict since you now explained it to me. :- )